# instantiating an object compilation errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've been working on a Java program, learning how to use and create constructors. For some reason, I keep getting an error, apprising me that my program can't find the symbol when instantiating an object.

Here's the resource class:

```
public class Pizza
{
   private int size;
   private String topping;
   private double cost;


   public Pizza()
   {
      size = 10;
      topping = "cheese";
      cost = 9.00;
   }

   public Pizza(int s, String t, double c)
   {
      s = size;
      t = topping;
      c = cost;
   }

   public int getSize() {
      return size;
   }

   public void setSize(int s) {
      s = size;
   }

   public String getTopping(){
      return topping;
   }

   public void setTopping(String t){
      topping = t;
   }

   public void setCost(double c) {
      cost = c;
   }   

   public double getCost(double c){
      return cost;
   }


   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format("%d inch %s pizza will cost $%,.2f\n", size, topping, cost);

   }
}
```

And here's the driver class:

```
public class PizzaTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Pizza orderTwo = new Pizza();

      System.out.printf("%-25s %s", "Pizza #1", orderTwo);
   }
}
```

I've been scrutinizing the code, but I can't seem to find any grammatical mistakes. Any advice is appreciated.  Compiler errors:

```
PizzaTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol Pizza orderTwo = new Pizza();
^ symbol: class Pizza location: class PizzaTest
PizzaTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol Pizza orderTwo = new Pizza();
^ symbol: class Pizza location: class PizzaTest
2 errors
```

Comment: Can you please share the exact text of the error, and where you're getting it?

Comment: PizzaTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      Pizza orderTwo = new Pizza();
      ^
  symbol:   class Pizza
  location: class PizzaTest
PizzaTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      Pizza orderTwo = new Pizza();
                           ^
  symbol:   class Pizza
  location: class PizzaTest
2 errors

Comment: Are `Pizza` and `PizzaTest` in the same package?

Comment: @Michael You can see for yourself that the errors are illegible when posted as comments. They should have been edited into your question and indeed they should have been present there from the beginning.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that exactly, but I created the resource class at school, and created the driver class at my house.

Comment: @Michael I don't know what you mean by that exactly, or how it is relevant where you wrote your code, but I am referring to the stack trace you omitted from your question and posted as a comment just above mine.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to import a reference to the Pizza class from the PizzaTest class.

```
import <packagename>.Pizza;
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `Pizza` is in a different package from `PizzaTest` and you haven't added the appopriate `import` statement into `PizzaTest`.

Answer (score -1):

This is where the error is

```
   public Pizza(int s, String t, double c)
   {
      s = size;
      t = topping;
      c = cost;
   }
```

It should be the other way around

```
   public Pizza(int s, String t, double c)
   {
      sise = s;
      topping = t;
      cost = c;
   }
```

Also in the setSize() function you have it the reversed way as well

Comment: I dont think it matters since he used the default constructor, and his default constructor does not call the other constructor.

Comment: I tried what you said, but no go. Still have the same error.

Comment: These are semantic errors but they don't explain his compile errors.

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be a parameter present in this method, remove the `double c`

```
public double getCost(double c){
  return cost;
}
```

Comment: This is a problem with the code, but is not going to fix the compiler issues.

Comment: Even if his classes were in the same package, he would still get an error on this `getCost(double c)` method.

Comment: No you wouldn't, that is a perfectly acceptable method, just a bit silly since the parameter is never used. To check, feel free to copy-paste the above code and run it as it most certainly compiles.

Comment: I guess you're right, even though I didnt test the code, but your argument does make sense. First time I've seen a getter with an argument, I thought it would cause a Runtime exception, pretty cool though.

Comment: No prob - a "getter" method is more a pattern than anything. They are all just methods as far as the compiler is concerned and you can do anything with them that you can with any other method.